# Access zookeeper properties for viewing the state of system

Tags: properties, open-source, apache-zookeeper, distributed-system

I am more of consumer of the zookeeper properties, In my current distributed system there are lots of properties in zookeeper but it is really hard to get what properties are in zk. I did google to get answer for my query but couldn't fulfil the thirst. The question is, Is there any way to visualize or access the zk properties from any API.

Comment: When you say visualize, do you mean instead of using the ZkCli tool, you wanted to see all the nodes from a GUI kind of a tool?

Comment: @MichelleTan : I want to see all the properties in the zookeeper? Can I do it with zkCli ?

Comment: Yea If you are talking about the zknodes properties you can do it with the zkCli